# Convert null of `List<Map<String, Object>> row` to empty String

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I have a `List<Map<String, Object>> row`.  I would like to check each row to see if it's null and replace the null value by an empty String.

Any recommendations, how to do that?

Comment: You mean replace the key `null` with the key `""` in each map in the list? Should be straight forward, hint: iterate, call `remove()` and `put()` on the maps.

Comment: Can you post example of your list before and after you manipulate it?

Comment: Check Kirti's answer below.

Comment: I recommend you consider handling `null` it at time of reading the `Object` item or inserting `Object` item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can iterate over it as

```
List<Map<String, Object>> row; 

for (Map<String, Object> map : row) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
    }
}
```

and make change in inner loop